# Qual protocolo de rede ideal para comunicar um Aplicativo com o Arduino?

Tags: android, arduino

Realizei a criação de um aplicativo através do Android Studio.
Possuo um arduino Mega,Shild Ethernet e sensores infravermelhos.

Gostaria de comunicar meu arduino com meu aplicativo através da internet.

Ex:
Fui viajar, quando o sensor infravermelho acionar, eu ser alertado em meu aplicativo.

Vi bastantes tutoriais, porem apenas com rede intranet.
Só lembrando, minha internet contempla o sistema IPV6.

Comment: protocolo http...  mas se é o mais ideal para o seu projeto, não posso afirmar.   No arduino ou em outro dispositivo na rede local, vc monta um pequeno servidor. A ideia seria o arduino enviar os dados para esse servidor local pela intranet. Esse servidor teria uma conexão com a internet e no seu smartphone vc teria um app para manter uma comunicação constante com o servidor.  Pesquise por “message queue”.

Comment: Eu já acho melhor usar "push notifications". O sistema operacional Android às vezes mata aplicativos que estão sem uso por um tempo e o push tem a vantagem de reiniciar esses aplicativos quando chega uma mensagem nova.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o padrão mqtt, este foi desenvolvido exatamente para ser super leve e ser utilizado em captura de sensores e sinais.

Utilizando o serviço https://data.sparkfun.com/ seu arduino faz um post http no estilo

```
http://data.sparkfun.com/input/sua-chave&nomeCampo=valor
```

O sparkfun anota os resultados, com data e hora, gera gráficos e você pode programar seu app android a consultar estes dados disponíveis no site.

Desta forma você não estará comunicando diretamente arduino - celular, mas evita ter a necessidade de abrir portas no seu roteador para expor na internet seu arduino, rede local e também a necessidade de acompanhar as alterações do seu ip público (ip externo do seu roteador) que geralmente não é fixo.